# Windows: FlushFileBuffers system call fails on network mapped drive

Tags: windows, winapi, system-calls, fsync

`fsync` doc states

> Calling  fsync() does not necessarily ensure that the entry in the directory containing the file has also reached disk.  For that an explicit fsync() on a file descriptor for the directory is
>          also needed.

I'm trying to sync a directory to the network mapped drive using SMB on windows, similar to what `fsync` does on Linux.

The following go code snippet which works fine if the directory is stored on a local drive but fails if it is on a network mapped folder.

```golang
func main() {
    dir := "Z:\\smb-test" // Path to network mapped drive
    f, err := openDir(dir)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    // Works fine if the path is located on a local disk but
    // fails if the directory is on a network mapped drive
    if err := f.Sync(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if err := f.Close(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func openDir(path string) (*os.File, error) {
    fd, err := openDirWin(path)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return os.NewFile(uintptr(fd), path), nil
}

func openDirWin(path string) (fd syscall.Handle, err error) {
    pathp, err := syscall.UTF16PtrFromString(path)
    if err != nil {
        return syscall.InvalidHandle, err
    }
    access := uint32(syscall.GENERIC_READ | syscall.GENERIC_WRITE)
    sharemode := uint32(syscall.FILE_SHARE_READ | syscall.FILE_SHARE_WRITE)
    createmode := uint32(syscall.OPEN_EXISTING)
    fl := uint32(syscall.FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS)
    return syscall.CreateFile(pathp, access, sharemode, nil, createmode, fl, 0)
}
```

The program fails with

```
Z:\\smb-test Incorrect function.
```

MSDN states that the handle passed in should either be a handle to a file, or to a volume, but says nothing about directories.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/FileAPI/nf-fileapi-flushfilebuffers

And FlushFileBuffers is not listed as a function that accepts directory handles
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/obtaining-a-handle-to-a-directory

I also noticed the flushfilebuffers system call fails with `Invalid Device Request` for a network mapped drive

[image: Untitled]

So the question is how do I sync a directory on windows?
Or is window's buffered I/O fundamentally different from POSIX and we don't need to flush a directory when a file inside it is modified?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: The above code is just a sample code. My intention is to sync directory contents to the file system on windows. See https://github.com/dgraph-io/badger/issues/699 for the actual issue.

Comment: Usually, when a network file is offline, a temporary cache file is generated locally (in C：\Windows\CSC. Unfortunately, very strict permissions prevent even administrators to peek inside the cache – only SYSTEM has full access.)and updated to the share folder when being online. You can also disable the caching by setting the properties of the share folder.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to my question is there's no way to sync directories on windows using system calls.`FlushFileBuffers` works for files and volumes, **NOT Directories**.

Read https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Windowsdesktop/en-US/847a735b-f21a-4be2-880b-12660e5b98b4/flushfilebuffers-system-call-fails-on-network-mapped-drive and 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/0e0b734b-2b73-414d-8833-8d2eed7043f6/sync-directories-on-windows
for more details.